# Can a user drop a HTML Shadow DOM into a blog post?

Tags: custom-post-types, posts

Is it possible for a user to drop a HTML Shadow DOM into a blog post? What is needed for that?

EDIT:
Maybe I should have written "... drop a definition of a custom element (script+style) + the custom element with a light DOM, all which the user can get as one file, built for drop in on a web page".

Is that more clear to anyone here?

---

EDIT 2:
Can someone perhaps tell if there is another forum on the internet where people might be able to answer this?

Comment: Can you give a specific example of what you're trying to do?

Comment: @JacobPeattie Thanks. Can you please tell me in what way the question is unclear to you?

Comment: Shadow DOM isn't something that gets "dropped into" a post. It's an API that a custom element or script can use. Are you trying to add a custom element to a post?

Comment: @JacobPeattie Ah, I see. Yes, I want a user to be able add a custom element to a post. A custom element with a light DOM and the script+style for the setup of the custom element (I thought it would be more clear if I wrote Shadow DOM...)

Comment: @JacobPeattie Is that you downvoting? Then please tell that you do so. Otherwise I have no idea if someone thinks the question is bad for some other reason (relevant or not!).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this plugin may make it possible:

> Code Embed – WordPress plugin | WordPress.org https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-embed-code/

However I don't use WordPress any more. Is there someone here that can confirm it will work?